# Are there any Python libraries for decoding Zigbee packets?

Tags: python, zigbee

I have some Zigbee sniffer hardware that can capture raw Zigbee bytes, e.g. see below.  Does anyone know of any Python libraries that could parse those bytes into Zigbee frames?

```
03 A3 0D 00 00 A9 4B 9E 86 06 00 00 00 2E 00 2D 61 88 F6 2F 37 B1 3D 00 00 08 1C
 B1 3D 00 00 1E 80 0F 3B 76 40 00 A2 13 00 47 33 C1 40 00 A2 13 00 00 00 02 E6 A
1 00 05 C1 E6 09 29 EC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this can help you as I don't know which is your hardware or what's your final goal, but you could take a look to this project:
https://github.com/andrewdodd/pyCCSniffer

I've been successfully using it on CC2531EMK.
Maybe it does what you need or you can hack it to fit your needs, as it's python.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is pretty close to what I need yes, quite helpful, thank you.